# How can I order my items in Pokemon Sword and Shield

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

There is only two sort functions, name and type.  Is it possible to order my items in my own way?

Especially I would like to order my pokeballs so that repeat balls are first, default pokeball in battle.

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/360663/124566)

Answer (score 1):

You can favorite an item or items then the sort option favorites first appears. This doesnt allow complete customization but will do the 2nd part of what you asked.